# Set QListWidget's items selection mandatory

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlistwidget

I have a QWizardPage in which I have a QListWidget. I wish that the next button will only be enabled when at least one item was selected in the QListWidget.
I tried to use registerField(...) and set it as mandatory, but it didn't seem to do anything.
I also tried to change the property in the registerField command to ("selectedItems()") and then it got stuck on disabled.

I really wouldn't want to create a new modified class for QWizardPage and re-implement isComplete(). Is there any other way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

QListWidgets have a signal for when an item is activated (selected). You can connect this signal to a slot that enables the next button.

You can use something like

```
QListWidget.itemActivated.connect(self.enable_button)
```

and in your `enable_button` function, you could just enable the button:

```
next_button.setEnabled(True)
```

This should allow you to do it without redoing any of your QWizardPage stuff

Comment: That doesn't work. I can't apply "setEnabled/setDisabled" on a button which is part of the QWizard.

Comment: If you post your code we might be able to help you better

Comment: I don't think that the entire `setupUi` function will interest you very much.
Basically the only thing that is relevant to the `QListWidget` is the following line:
`self.wizard_page_features.registerField('features*', self.features_list)` which is on the `__init__` function of the modified Wizard class.

btw: `self.wizard_page_features` is the `QWizardPage` with the `QListWidget` in it, and `self.features_list` is the `QListWidget` itself.

Comment: This is the addition you suggested (which didn't work for me):
`self.features_list.itemActivated.connect(self.enable_button)` (on the `__init__`)
and

`def enable_button(self):
        self.button(self.NextButton).setEnabled(True)`

Comment: I think that the problem is that initializePage() sets the currentRow() of the QListWidget to -1, and immediately after the painting of the gui, it becomes 0. Since the values are different - it counts that field as "filled"

Comment: Another thing I've tried was to promote QListWidget to a modified class. Then define a function which counts the selected items and return int.
Then I tried the register the field under the slot of countCheckedItems (which I defined myself). Still didn't work. I think there might be a problem with PyQt and registerField.